# Arduino IDE でspresenseをプログラムする際に2つのセンサが競合する場合の対処法が知りたい

Tags: spresense

spresenseのメインボードにToFセンサ(サンハヤト株式会社製MM-S50MV)とWi-Fiモジュール(IDY株式会社製is110B)を同時に使用したいのですが、仕様書の示すように接続すると一部同じピンを共有してしまうために競合を起こしうまく動きません。こういった場合の対処法ご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらご教授願いたいです。使用しているピンは以下の画像の通りです。
[image: Wi-Fiモジュールpin]
[image: ToFセンサpin]

Answer (score 0):

「仕様書の示すように接続すると、競合を起こしうまく動きません」というのであれば、仕様書に誤りがあるのでしょう。
メーカーのSpresense担当部署に問い合わせるべきと考えます。

Comment: ToFセンサーとWi-Fiモジュールそれぞれの仕様書はそれぞれで問題はないです。ただWi-Fiモジュールの使用するピンは競合していない一部のピンのみしか設定を変えられないことがIDYのサイトで分かっており、ToFセンサーは通信方式で使用するピンを変更できますがいずれにせよ競合を起こしたままになります。
spresenseの公式サイトでも問い合わせは受け付けておらず、ここで質問せよとのことでした。

Answer (score 0):

質問の意図があまりわからないので、間違ったコメントになるかもしれませんが、
どちらもSPIを使うモジュールなので、そのままでは動かないと思います。

どちらのボードもCSピンだけのアサインを変更することができないので、
どちらかをUARTで使うしかないでしょうが、見た感じ、ToFのジャンパJ1を切り替えることで、
UARTにすることができそうです。（やったっことないですが…。）

一方、WiFiはTypeCである場合、サンプルコードを見る限りUARTは使用していないので、
競合しないのではないでしょうか？

TypeA/Bの場合、以下を見る限り、
https://idy-design.com/product/is110b.html

ジャンパ抵抗を変更することで切り替えられそうですよ。

ご参考まで。

Comment: そうですか、そのあたりの知識がないのでまた調べつつやってみます。ありがとうございます。